# How to resolve "The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'ControlTemplate'"?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, storyboard, controltemplate

I've added a control template to an UpdateBtn, following this [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299550/display-dot-dot-dot-progress-in-a-wpf-button) but I get an error stating that `Triggers` property isn't found on ControlTemplate. The idea is to bind the storyboard to the `IsEnabled` property of the button.

```
Error   5   The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'ControlTemplate'.
```

I researched the error and it seems the property is part of [ControlTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.triggers(v=vs.110).aspx), and this is a WPF app not Windows. So not sure why the error is being shown in the xaml designer.

Can anyone advise on the where I've gone wrong with the implementation?

The XAML for the button and associated ns are as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="MongoDBApp.Views.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:email_validator="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.Validator"
        Title="Orders Dashbord"
        Width="800"
        Height="500">

    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Customer">
                <Grid>

                    <Button x:Name="updateBtn"
                            Width="75"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}"
                            Content="Update">
                        <Button.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock>Updates customer record</TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </Button.ToolTip>
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content" Duration="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="Loading"/>
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="Loading."/>
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="Loading.."/>
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="Loading..."/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>


                </Grid>
            </TabItem>           
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your XAML structure is

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         ...
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</Button.Template>
```

but you need something like

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          ...
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

Comment: That was the solution, I hadn't specified the <ControlTemplate> and the target type which is why the error was thrown.