# C# WPF Animated label content is not being shown

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, label, controltemplate

I am trying to animate the content of a label in order to do:

```
Loading
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...
```

again:

```
Loading
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...
```

and so on like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299550/display-dot-dot-dot-progress-in-a-wpf-button).

Below the code:

```
<Label Grid.Row="2" x:Name="CurrentTask" 
       FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="18" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" 
       Foreground="White" Content="Loading">
    <Label.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content" Duration="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="Loading"/>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="Loading."/>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="Loading.."/>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="Loading..."/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Label.Template>
</Label>
```

The problem is that label content is not visible in the wpf window. It is not being shown. What am I doing wrong?

Also in the lines of type:

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="Loading"/>
```

Instead of hard-coding the value I would like to concatenate the label content to the dots, how can I do this? I do not want to repeat the "Loading" string in each `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame`.

**UPDATE**:
Instead of raise trigger on IsEnabled=True, I have used label.loaded as below for example in the case of applying label style:

```
    <Label Grid.Row="2" x:Name="CurrentTask" 
           FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="18" FontStyle="Italic"  
           Foreground="White" Content="Loading">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content" Duration="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="Loading"/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="Loading."/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="Loading.."/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="Loading..."/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the Triggers, your ControlTemplate is empty, so obviously nothing is shown.

You could add a ContentPresenter, and also remove the Storyboard.TargetName. It looks also odd that your Trigger acts on `IsEnabled` set to false.

```
<Label.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">

        <ContentPresenter/>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content" Duration="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="Loading"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="Loading."/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="Loading.."/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="Loading..."/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Label.Template>
```

However, what you actually might want to have is a Style Trigger instead of a ControlTemplate Trigger:

```
<Label ...>
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content" Duration="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="Loading"/>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="Loading."/>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="Loading.."/>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="Loading..."/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

---

For the repeated "Loading" string in the Content, just use two Labels, one with a fixed "Loading" string, the other with the dots, and adjust their Padding. Or better, two TextBlocks:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Loading"/>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text" Duration="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value=""/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="."/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value=".."/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="..."/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hi Clemens! In order to do a quick test, I have tried the second of your solutions, setting label style trigger but it is not working. Label content always remains "Loading". I have a MVVM app with a window and this label, and this window is a splash screen. This splash screen is called (by instantiating constructor) from the view constructor. Finally it is shown by calling Show(). All this stuff is being doing using a thread with apartment state set to STA...

Comment: ...In the meantime, in the view constructor the flow continues , I set datacontext with the viewModel and then a database request is performed in the view model constructor. When this finishes, splash screen is closed. Maybe it is due to the thread that it is not working?

Comment: As I said, it looks odd that your Trigger acts on IsEnabled set to false. Is that intended?

Comment: I've changed it to `<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">` in all example, as triggering on `False` doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Hi Clemens again! Your solution works like a charm! The problem commented in previous posts was due to the thread. I was not managing it well. Thanks!